# Replace specific dataframe columns values with blank

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe column (df) which I am trying to replace 999 values with blank. The head of the unadjusted column looks like:

```
Name: IntValue, dtype: int32
0    999
1     50
2     50
3     55
4     58
```

I would like the adjusted column to be adjusted to look like:

```
Name: IntValue, dtype: int32
0    
1     50
2     50
3     55
4     58
```

I am using:

```
rawDatabase[newFieldTrunc].replace(999, "")
```

But it's not changing the columns data at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are replacing over a copy of the `Series`, not the actual `Series`.

```
rawDatabase[newFieldTrunc].replace(999, "", inplace=True)
```

Or

```
rawDatabase[newFieldTrunc] = rawDatabase[newFieldTrunc].replace(999, "")
```

PS: It is advised to use Python native `None` or `np.nan` as a placeholder for blanks instead of a blank text `""`.

Answer (score 0):

To alter the DataFrame inplace, you need to set the `inplace` argument to `True`:

```
rawDatabase[newFieldTrunc].replace(999, "", inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

As alternative to the previous answers:

```
 rawDatabase[newFieldTrunc] = rawDatabase[newFieldTrunc].replace(999, "")
```